# How do you enable multithreading on nginx and apache

Tags: php, multithreading, apache, nginx, pecl

I am trying to run a multithreading block of code on php, and lm using Nginx, the block of code is giving an internal error, and l think multithreading is not enabled, How do you Enable multi threading on nginx? as an addition, l am also interested in how l can set it up in apache.

Comment: It has nothing to do with nginx.

Comment: How do l implement Multithreading in php @AlexeyTen